# Evaluation of angular integral in 1 dimention

Tags: integration

I am trying to get this integral in 1 dimension
$$
\psi_n(z)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}dx\int\frac{d\Omega_n}{\Omega_n}\frac{1}{z-x\cos\theta}
$$
where $d\Omega_d$ is the element of solid angle in $d$ dimensions, $\Omega$ is $4\pi, 2\pi$ and $2$ in $3,2$ and $1$ dimension respectively.
What is  $d\Omega$ in $1D$?
The result should be like this:

$$ 
\psi_1(z)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{z+1}{z-1}
$$
**Edit:**
Also the integral in $2$ and $3$ dimention is as follows:

$$
\psi_2(z)=z-Sign(\Re z)\sqrt{z^2-1}
$$
$$
\psi_3(z)=\frac{z}{2}+\frac{1-z^2}{4}\ln\frac{z+1}{z-1}
$$
derivation in $3D$ was srightforward.

Comment: Is $z$ a complex number?

Comment: Also, what is the context of the problem?  Physics, field theory, topology, ... ?

Comment: Yes, $z$ is complex. This integral appears is Lindhard Function,  Linear response function in electron gas theory. Ref: "QUANTUM THEORY OF THE ELECTRON LIQUID
" ,  Giuliani, 2005, p 161

Comment: The Fermi surface in one dimension consist of two points...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
the Fermi surface in 1D consists of two opposite points at the real line. Choosing your parameterization where the Fermi momentum seems to be absorbed in $x=k/k_f$, this points are obviously $\pm1$. 
It's therefore a good idea to replace $\frac{d\Theta_1}{\Theta_1}=\frac{\delta(\Theta)+\delta(\Theta-\pi)}{2}$ where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac distribution. Doing the trivial angular integration we are left with:
$$
\Psi_1(z)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1dx\left(\frac{1}{z-x}+\frac{1}{z+x}\right)
$$ 
The remaining integral is also standard and gives us the desired result
$$
\Psi_1(z)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\log(z+1)}{\log(z-1)}
$$

Edit: One has to be careful at $|z|\geq1$ but, in principle this is the way to go.
I think this equality should hold if $z$ has finite imaginary part, which can be assumed for causality reasons.

Comment: Good replacement. Thank you.